# An element that has v-if isn't updated as expected

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Lately I've been trying to use VueJS to create a small project and I have encountered this problem. So I have this navigation bar that includes a Log Out Button element that'd only shown if someone has already logged in. This is my Navbar before I logged in.

[Before Login Navbar. No Log Out Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPbXd.png)

After I logged in, my navbar'd be like this.

[after logged in Navbar. Log Out Button exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aGBW.png)

This is my code for this navbar component.

```html
<div id="logout-button" v-if="isLoggedIn">
      <button v-on:click="logOut">Log Out</button>
</div>

....


<script>
export default {
  name: "NavigationBar",
  data: function () {
    return {
      isLoggedIn: false,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    if (localStorage.isLoggedIn !== undefined) {
      this.isLoggedIn = localStorage.isLoggedIn;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...
    logOut: function () {
      localStorage.isLoggedIn = false;
      localStorage.access = null;
      localStorage.refresh = null;
      location.reload();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

What I've been trying is whenever the log out button clicked, I'd change the value of a key in my local storage, named "isLoggedIn" from "true" to "false". After that, I'd reload the page and when the page reached mounted, the component's data named "isLoggedIn"'d be changed with the new value of my local storage which is now "false". Hence, my expectation is the button wouldnt' be there.

The problem is, whenever I clicked log out, the Log Out Button'd be always there as if I didn't change the value that hopefully doesn't evaluated as "true" in the v-if. I don't know which or what is the problem since I'm new to Vue and I really hope you guys could tell me what it is. Thank you very much!

Comment: cast it `this.isLoggedIn = !!!localStorage.isLoggedIn;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `logOut()` method, you're only changing the value in the `localStorage`, however the `v-if="isLoggedin"` is binded to the component's data so you also need to update that.

```js
logOut: function () {
  localStorage.isLoggedIn = false;
  localStorage.access = null;
  localStorage.refresh = null;
  this.isLoggedIn = false
  location.reload();
},
```

Additionally, you can only store strings in the localStorage, so you need to evaluate your string to return a boolean for your component's data.

```js
this.isLoggedIn = (localStorage.isLoggedIn === 'true')
```

Here is a small jsfiddle for you to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/6rv7j5bg/

Comment: Hello, thank you for your suggestions. I've tried it but this thing too didn't work in this case. And for additional, I expect my component's data "isLoggedIn" would be changed according to my local storage data when the lifecycle of my component reached "mounted". However, that too didn't work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Updated the answer and added a jsfiddle as example

Comment: Hey, thank you for your update and I believe your suggestions worked just fine. :) I just know that local storage can only store strings and not any other type. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try using:
`localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", false)`

and:
`localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn")`

and see if it makes any difference!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your suggestions. I've tried your suggestions but unfortunately, this didn't work on my case. :( The way I'm accessing the local storage is based on the official documentation by vue here https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/client-side-storage.html. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried removing the localStorage attributes completely?